# Different Dates on Google Analytics and Shopify Sales Data

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

I've got a problem matching shopify data with google analytics data. The numbers were more than a few hundred dollars off, so I figured it was a bigger problem than the normal problems.

I exported the shopify sales and the sales counted in google analytics. The values and quanities of orders were the same, but the dates were different. In GA, it was saying a sale was on 3/6/2015, but shopify had it as 3/16/2015. I checked with the client and they had received that order on the 16th. So somehow GA had the time 10 days off. And this is happening on many orders, but not all.

Have you seen this before? And how is shopify sending an incorrect date to GA/how is GA reading an incorrect date?

I'm not sure what more information to give here. I checked the implementations and everything seemed normal.

Comment: Give more details about your implementation. Without knowing that, it's impossible to speculate.

Answer (score 0):

in the addTrans and addItem calls you're passing the data to, there is no formally passed date. GA related the instance of the addTrans to whatever time it was received.

what % of orders would you say are being dated incorrectly?

Comment: 70% of them are being dated incorrectly. In my understanding, it is the google analytics code on the checkout page that sends the data to google analytics, so is the date somehow being messed with at that point?

Comment: Try querying using GA custom report or the API explorer https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ and pull a list of transactions, source/medium, visit number and browser and day and hour. See if one transaction has more than 1 row for each of the breakdowns. There's nothing explicit you can do to set the time of the transaction as it's determined by when GA's servers processed the hit from the addTrans method.